# Map over PatternSynonyms args before matching w/ ViewPatterns?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I was recently trying to refactor an ADT -- where the number of constructors has grown combinatorically -- into a backwards-compatible set representation:

```
data Tag = TagFoo | TagBar !Text | TagBaz !Int ... -- many more
           deriving (Eq, Generic, Ord, Show)

newtype Label = Label (HashSet Tag)
                deriving (Eq, Generic, Show)
```

To this end, I defined several pattern synonyms to the effect of:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

pattern Foo :: Label
pattern Foo <- Tags [TagFoo] where
  Foo = Label $ HashSet.singleton TagFoo

-- (let's say a lone TagBar is invalid)

pattern FooWithBar :: Text -> Label
pattern FooWithBar b <- Tags [TagFoo, TagBar b] where
   FooWithBar b = Label $ HashSet.fromList [TagFoo, TagBar b]
```

with `Tags` pattern defined as:

```
 pattern Tags :: [Tag] -> Label
 pattern Tags ts <- ((\(Label ts') -> sort $ HashSet.toList ts') -> ts)
```

Unfortunately, this form is error prone, as it requires users to provide the `[Tag]` list in the correct `Ord`er. Otherwise, a pattern like `Tags [TagBar "x", TagFoo]` won't match `Label $ HashSet.fromList [TagBar "x", TagFoo]`. (Not doing the `sort` is even worse, though, as then the order of tags would be arbitrary).

Ideally, Haskell (or unordered-containers?) would provide a way to pattern-match elements of a `HashSet`s. But another way could be to map the `ts` argument of `Tags ts` pattern through `HashSet.fromList` and then compare the resulting sets:

```
pattern Tags ts <- ((\(Label ts') -> ts' == HashSet.fromList ts) -> True)
```

This is impossible, however, because arguments of a pattern synonym cannot be used by a view pattern function. But trying to do the transformation outside of the view function:

```
pattern Tags ts <- ((\(Label ts') -> ts') -> HashSet.fromList ts == ts')
```

is also impossible, since the part after `->` is a pattern and doesn't permit function application.

Is there some other way of defining the pattern synonym that would allow this kind of matching?

Comment: `unordered-containers` can't define such a synonym either!

Answer (score 1):

Does `Tags` really need to be a pattern? What's wrong with simply providing a function:

```
toLabel :: [Tags] -> Label
```

and have users use guards:

```
someFunction lab | lab == toLabel [TagFoo, TagBar "bar"] = ...
```